# Error Swagger - could not resolve reference

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

In swagger I have problem on POST rest like this

```
Errors
Resolver error at paths./api/v1/getEntity/{integrationCode}.post.responses.200.schema.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Map«string,object» does not exist in document
```

rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/")
public class RetrieveController {

@PostMapping(value = "getEntity/{integrationCode}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>> getList(@PathVariable String integrationCode, @RequestBody RetrieveParam retrieveParam) throws JsonProcessingException {
List<Map<String, Object>> integration = ...
return ResponseEntity.ok(integration);
```

input parameter json object looks like

```
{
  "fields": [
    "string"
  ],
  "filter": [
    {
      "comparison": "EQ",
      "fieldName": "string",
      "fieldValue": {},
      "operation": "AND"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 0
  },
  "path": "string",
  "sorts": [
    {
      "fieldName": "string",
      "type": "ASC"
    }
  ]
}
```

after add SwaggerConfig rules (rest return response entity like `List<Map<String, Object>>` )

```
.alternateTypeRules(
                    AlternateTypeRules.newRule(
                            typeResolver.resolve(List.class, WildcardType.class),
                            typeResolver.resolve(Map.class, String.class, Object.class)
                    )
            )
```

json object looks like

```
{
  "fields": {
    "additionalProp1": {},
    "additionalProp2": {},
    "additionalProp3": {}
  },
  "filters": {
   "additionalProp1": {},
    "additionalProp2": {},
    "additionalProp3": {}
  },
  "pagination": {
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 0
  },
  "path": "string",
  "sorts": {
    "additionalProp1": {},
    "additionalProp2": {},
    "additionalProp3": {}
  }
}
```

after change SwaggerConfig rules about

```
          typeResolver.resolve(List.class, Map.class),
          typeResolver.resolve(Map.class, String.class, Object.class), Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
```

the error did not go away

after next config rules:

```
typeResolver.resolve(List.class, WildcardType.class),
                                    typeResolver.resolve(Map.class,
                                            typeResolver.resolve(String.class, Object.class))
```

deploy exception:

```
Factory method 'api' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create TypeBinding for class java.lang.String with 1 type parameter: class expects 0
```

Pls, help me:

- how to configure rules swagger for `List<Map<String, Object>>` ?
- why after use `WildcardType` in config my json looks strange?

Comment: Is this Springfox? Can you also post the annotations for the `/api/v1/getEntity/{integrationCode}` endpoint?

Comment: @Helen UP (edit post). Yes, its springfox